# Can you check if T inherits from IEnumerable<T> then use methods available to IEnumerable<T>?

Tags: c#, .net, types, ienumerable, system.reflection

So I'm creating a generic method, obviously the signature therefore can take any type of object. The problem I have is I want the user to be able to either just send one object to my method, or a collection (I know, different interface from IEnumerable) of objects. Now because (T obj) could be one object, or it could be a list or an array of objects, Im not sure how to check and alter behaviour depending on if it is a collection or not.

This is what I have, and I'm getting a compiler error CS1061, T does not contain a definition for FirstOrDefault. Which makes sense, because it might not. But as far as I can tell my conditional should have checked if it does or not.

```
if (typeof(IEnumerable<T>).IsAssignableFrom(obj.GetType()))
        {
            foreach (var info in obj.FirstOrDefault().GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                members.Add(info.Name, info.GetValue(obj).ToString());
            }
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var info in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                members.Add(info.Name, info.GetValue(obj).ToString());
            }
        }
```

In case it makes any difference, members is a Dictionary<string, string>. At this stage I'm only trying to get it to accept both collections and single objects, I can work out the behaviour later.

Answer (score 1):

You have to cast `obj` to `IEnumerable<T>` before you can access `FirstOrDefault`. And in your case, you can do that with the [is](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is) operator.

```
if (obj is IEnumerable<T> e)
{
    foreach (var info in e.FirstOrDefault().GetType().GetProperties))
    ...
}
...
```

Your code was fine as is, except you were using `obj` without first casting. For example you could have done this instead:

```
if (typeof(IEnumerable<T>).IsAssignableFrom(obj.GetType()))
{
    var e = (IEnumerable<T>)obj;
    foreach (var info in e.FirstOrDefault().GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        members.Add(info.Name, info.GetValue(obj).ToString());
    }
    ...
```

As you can see though, using `is` is shorter and easier to read.

Comment: One more question, the code is now compiling fine and it runs, but my conditional isnt being hit, its always being skipped. I'm using List<T> in my xunit test to pass in multiple objects right now but obj is IEnumerable<T> e is returning false. Is it there some other way I have to cast it to check if the obj inherits from IEnumerable<T>?

Comment: I'd have to see more context -- maybe the whole method.

Comment: I figured it out, because as I said its a Generic method that takes any object T, when you say IEnumerable<T> the compiler tries to fill T with the type that is being used, so its kind of trying to make it an IEnumerable of itself. So for the conditional check I used a method that returns true if T is or inherits from IEnumerable. Also this thread got closed pointing me to a thread that does not answer myquestion, and now I cant even post my own answer.